# Cannot implicitly convert type bool to System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm tying to follow the async await structure as described on msdn [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

So I have an `async` task:

```
    public async void Starter()
    {

        CC = new CustomClass();

        Task<bool> newTask = CC.MethodThatReturnsBool();

        // DO SOME VISUAL THINGS

        bool b = await newTask;

        }
    }
```

But I'm getting a compile-stopping error around the `CC.MethodThatReturnsBool();` as shown by my question header.

How do I get my bool in the right format? I tried randomly casting (Task) in front of the erroneous method call but it just removed the "implicitly" from my error message!

**I'm using:**

VS Community 2017 and .NET Framework 4.7

Comment: If `MethodThatReturnsBool` really returns a `bool` then where is the asynchronous operation to be awaited?

Comment: Well, it returns a bool after lots of intranet back-and-forth - I think what you're hinting at is that the method I'm calling needs to be an `async` task ? If I'm to do this then I think I need to do a lot of wrapping around my existing methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, this returns a `bool`:

```
CC.MethodThatReturnsBool()
```

So you'd store it as such:

```
bool newBool = CC.MethodThatReturnsBool();
```

Which, it would seem, means that there are no asynchronous operations to be awaited.  Simplifying:

```
public void Starter()
{
    CC = new CustomClass();

    bool b = CC.MethodThatReturnsBool();

    // do something with your bool?
}
```

It's not clear why you're expecting to `await` anything, and there may indeed be more to this that you're not showing, but if the method you're calling is synchronous then there's no need to await it.

Side note: `async void` is a *really bad idea*.  It only exists for compatibility with UI event handlers and such.  If you're writing anything that you control, don't use `async void`.

---

**Edit:**

Based on your update to the question, it *sounds like* what's happening here is that you have a long-running *synchronous* process that you'd like to not block the UI thread?  You can wrap something in a `Task`, perhaps something like this:

```
bool b = await Task.Run(() => new CustomClass().MethodThatReturnsBool());
```

So perhaps overall you're looking for something more like this (untested)?:

```
public async Task Starter()
{
    Task<bool> newTask = Task.Run(() => new CustomClass().MethodThatReturnsBool());

    // DO SOME VISUAL THINGS

    bool b = await newTask;

    // do something with your bool?
}
```

To elaborate on a previous point, note that the overall method is now `async Task` instead of `async void`.  This makes `Starter` itself awaitable, as void otherwise would not be.

*Ideally* of course, `MethodThatReturnsBool` should *itself* be `async` if it is internally performing various I/O bound operations which cause its delay.  (As implied in your comment on the question above.)  That may involve refactoring elsewhere in the system, but in the long run is the preferable approach.

Comment: OK so I stuck in a line that says in between calling `MethodThatReturnsBool` and waiting for it, there is some visual stuff that will happen (update status, change windowstate etc)

Comment: @jamheadart: If I understand correctly, you have a long-running synchronous operation that you don't want to block the UI?  I've updated the answer.

Comment: yes this is exactly the approach I'm looking for, and yes I'd like to go back and get my methods async - they're generally all relying on POST/GET requests anyway so by nature they could be all wrapped async... I am applying your answer and will test in a few minutes...

Comment: This seems to work great, I am still getting my head round the potential and engineering behind it, and how my method is now a task itself... but thanks for the pointers so far!!